# Barycenter of image projection

Tags: c#, image

I have a binary image projection like this for example.

[image: Vertical projection of my image]

I want to calculate the barycenter of this projection. What should i do?

Comment: what i want to calculate is the index of the middel curve area. in this exampel it is 230. i want to canculate the index for any projection i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `N` values in `x[i]`

```
long num=0, den=0;
for(int i=0, i<N, i++)
{
    num += i*x[i];
    den += x[i];
}
int i_cen = (int)( num/den );
```